# Animate dropdown button AND have list appear?

Tags: jquery, html

The problem I have is on lines 45-47 in the second link. If that code is there, the button will animate when clicked (which is good) BUT the dropdown items ("About," "Archive," "Contact") will not appear. If I take lines 45-47 away, the dropdown items appear but no animation occurs. How do I get both the animation AND dropdown items to appear when the button is clicked?

I've been trying to incorporate code from here:
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_icon.asp

This is in my `header.php` file:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction(this)"
            class="dropbtn">

            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>

            </button>

  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">

    <a href="http://SITE/?page_id=289">About</a>
    <a href="http://SITE/?page_id=148">Archive</a>
    <a href="http://SITE/?page_id=318">Contact</a>

  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}


function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}

</script>
```

This is in my `style.css` file:

```
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I remove all what I tought was unnecessary...
And renamed some classes for clarity.

I think that is what you look for.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content 
And animates bars in the button */

$(".MenuToggle").click(function() {
    $("#myMenu").toggleClass("showMenu");
    $(this).children("div").toggleClass("change");
});
```

```css
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.change.bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change.bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change.bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}

.showMenu{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button class="MenuToggle">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
    </button>

    <div id="myMenu" class="showMenu">
        <a href="http://SITE/?page_id=289">About</a>
        <a href="http://SITE/?page_id=148">Archive</a>
        <a href="http://SITE/?page_id=318">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! I'm having some trouble with formatting it though so that it looks like it did before. I've tried changing it, but I think line 57 is not working and maybe other parts.  http://paste.ofcode.org/LGS3amwsMveAmknDESpQY7
https://s18.postimg.org/z9pfnkkux/menu.jpg
The left side is how it was before when the button is clicked.
The right side is the new code. The button moves over and the list is not vertical.

Comment: This is the first link's code before changes: http://paste.ofcode.org/z7UAHAuf4ZcfmkgQ9brzG5

Comment: On line 57, I suggested `display:none` assuming the menu was not shown by default on page load. Toggling this class mean removing it if it has OR adding it if it hasn't.

Comment: I tried `display:none`, and removing it entirely. It didn't seem to do anything. In the picture (s18.postimg.org/z9pfnkkux/menu.jpg ), the menu does show when the button is clicked, but all the style elements are not working.

Comment: When I change it to: '.showMenu {display:block;}', the menu shows with the right style when it is NOT clicked (where it is supposed to be hiding/none), and when I click the button, it turns to the "X" and without the right style. So, I think the answer is close to this. What class/element controls what the menu will look like when the button is clicked?

Comment: To add style to `myMenu`, you probably have to keep the other classes you have, which defines the style of that `div`. You can use more than one class on a `div`, separating them with a space. So your code should be something like `<div id="myMenu" class="showMenu anotherClass">` where "anotherClass" defines the style. "showMenu" is only used to toggle the display.